# PNY GTX 970 not showing any more than 140mb of memory used

Tags: memory, graphics-card, nvidia-graphics-card

So I just bought this GPU recently and it's been working fine. I've been playing The Witcher 3 on ultra settings around 60 fps with no stuttering or anything bad. I downloaded some monitoring software because I was curious about how much memory was being used in The Witcher 3 and wanted to see if it was going over 3.5gb (due to the seperate 500mb cache in the gtx 970's)

Although when I run either MSI afterburner or GPU-Z it never shows my memory usage as more than 140mb. I figured this is not even possible since my game is running fine but am really baffled on why it's doing this. Anyone know any way to fix this?

[image: Example of the GPU memory usage at 2.9%**]

It stays at 2.9% even if I'm unpaused. I couldn't take the screenshot with the overlay unless I paused the game in windowed mode.

Comment: Okay. Let me get this straight. You're having no problem with the game you're just upset it's giving you a number that doesn't seem right. 3.5gb is A LOT. Trust the software here. Trust the software.

Comment: Do you have any other games which you can test? Crysis 3 will mercilessly use all 2GB of my VRAM. Sounds like a software bug in the VRAM detection process. I would wait and see if a future GPU-Z update will display the correct VRAM.